# Message passing with czmq

Tags: c, zeromq

I'm trying to use czmq, the first test was ok with the inproc protocol and if the "puller" and the "pusher" in the same program. 
But I want to use it on different processus, I also tried ipc and tcp, and I can not achieve to make communicate the server and the client.

The server:

```
#include <czmq.h>
int main (void)
{

    zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();


    void *reader = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_PULL);

    int rc = zsocket_connect (reader, "tcp://localhost:5555");
    printf("wait for a message...\n");

    char *message = zstr_recv (reader);

    printf("Message: %s",message);

    zctx_destroy (&ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

and the client:

```
#include <czmq.h>
int main (void)
{

    zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();

    void *writer = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_PUSH);

    int rc = zsocket_bind (writer, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == service);
    zstr_send (writer, "HELLO");

    zsocket_destroy (ctx, writer);

    return 0;

}
```

Could you tell me what is wrong with my code. I have also tried other sample codes found, but without more success.

**Update**

The server is waiting for messages in `zstr_recv`, but the messages send by the client triggers nothing on the server process.

Comment: Does that mean, there was not a single example code that you have seen running on your localhost correctly as demonstrated in ZeroMQ API documentation and other examples? N.b.: your prototyping efforts have better use **tcp:** transport-class and after the principal functionality is running, adapt the transport-class related behaviour for another one of your choice.

Comment: no one runs correctly, except the inproc example: http://czmq.zeromq.org/

Comment: Sounds promising, ZeroMQ has no troubles per-se. **inproc:** transport-class is a memory-mapped one. Does your effective user-rights and system setup allow your code to access filesystem (ipc: nodes) & network services/port-numbers (tcp:, pgm:, epgm:)?

Comment: I do not have network restrictions. And I tried to run the client and the server as root and it's the same: the server is not receiving the messages from the client.

Comment: So, try to do two things -- make ZMQ_PUSH side to send more messages with Ordinal#UUID + TimeStamp down the line + re-design ZMQ_PULL side to read in non-blocking mode, as it is common in MVC/GUI event-loops and handle the cases, where no message arrives in the meantime between the scheduler re-visits ZMQ_PULL reads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sending the message, the client process is destroying the socket too quickly. With inproc, you "get away with it" because inproc is fast, while TCP has to go through more hurdles before the message gets to the TCP stack.

It is true that zsocket_destroy() should block until the message is sent, if ZMQ_LINGER = -1 (the default with raw ZMQ), but the default linger for CZMQ is 0. That means dropping in-transit messages when the socket is destroyed.

Try setting the linger (with zctx_set_linger) to something bigger than zero; 10ms perhaps, but use whatever value is good for you.

Comment: You are right! I had a ''sleep(10)'' just after ''zstr_send'' and the message is correctly transmitted. Thank you.